# Kafka and Spark Streaming performance issues

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, ambari

My target is to run a cluster of Spark Streaming instances to process data with some simple algorithms. For example, first would be to

```
def updateFunction(newValues, runningCount):
    if runningCount is None:
        runningCount = 0
    return sum(newValues, runningCount)

# Produces two tuples from each one, and sums its values. Then orders the result.
digest = ks.flatMap(producePerAorB)\
           .updateStateByKey(updateFunction)\
           .transform(lambda rdd: rdd.sortBy(lambda x: x[1], ascending=False))
```

I'm facing a lot of performance issues when plugging Kafka to a cluster of Spark.

A description of my setup:

- I'm using a cluster of 6 beefy AWS m4.xlarge, so hardware shouldn't be an issue
- 24 partitions in Kafka topic. Tried with 1, 6, 12 and 48, seems to be the best. The data is produced by simply piping files to console-producer.
- YARN as master. Tuned it to every possible setting: larger and fewer containers, smaller and more.
- Pyspark. Spark 1.5.2. Everything is set up with Ambari.
- I've tried with Direct Streaming and with a Receiver. The first one is supposed to be easier to tune, but it turns out that it completely neglects parallelism, contrary to what documentation says. Now with the receiver approach it seems to perform better. However, after a few minutes, I start getting lots of *YarnHistoryService: Discarding event* messages, which probably means that I'm losing data. Not much info about it on the internet, and I've diven into Spark's code to try to decipher it. Apparently is the monitoring service of YARN, but it just doesn't look right and they start to pile up and data doesn't get refreshed well, so it's probably wrong.
- I'm using these settings for Spark/Kafka:
  --conf spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled=true \
  --conf spark.streaming.kafka.maxRate=5000 \
  and they don't seem to do anything at all.
- I've tried with variations of the code and the simplest possible operations, and still get the same errors.

Looking at the performance, and specially those errors, I guess I'm doing something terribly wrong. I'm a bit out of ideas, after speculating convoluted scenarios that didn't help much. I would expect Spark and Kafka to be a bit easier to set up!

Any pointers would be appreciated
Thank you

Comment: it is very hard to say what is wrong with the detail you've provided. Is the kafka cluster hosted on the same machines as spark? are your initial reading tasks node_local ? can you partition the data in kafka? can you try using Spark 1.6.0 and mapWithState instead of updateStateByKey? How much data is being shuffled by spark? Are you monitoring activity on those 6 machines to see if there are bottlenecks (i.e. CPU & Network)?

Comment: If you're using the receiver-less method, make sure to set `spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition` -- As I recall this will throttle the input rate. This setting is x per second per partition. See the bottom of http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html.